# Pop up messagebox when print job is done

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using excel VBA I have code that print excel sheet but problem is I want to show messagebox when the print job is done so I will start next print process.

I have following code :

```
 xlshtSal.Activate
    Dim i, totalRows, MidCount As Long
    i = 2
    'xlapp.Visible = False
    Do While xlshtInput.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Or xlshtInput.Cells(i, 1) <> Null

        xlshtSal.Range("C12") = xlshtInput.Cells(i, 1)
        xlshtSal.PrintOut
        xlshtSal.Range("C12") = ""

        i = i + 1
    Loop

   'here I want Messagebox 

    If MsgBox("Column 'A' print is completed now printing Column 'B' ? ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Print wizard") = vbYes Then
        i = 2
        Do While xlshtInput.Cells(i, 2) <> "" Or xlshtInput.Cells(i, 2) <> Null

            xlshtSal.Range("C12") = xlshtInput.Cells(i, 2)
            xlshtSal.PrintOut
            xlshtSal.Range("C12") = ""

            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "sorry, Column B is Not printed", vbExclamation
    End If
```

Comment: `Dim i, totalRows, MidCount As Long` is equivalent to `Dim i As Variant, totalRows As Variant, MidCount As Long`, which is probably not your intention.

Comment: no @JohnColeman

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you want. You have to go outside the Excel Object Model and interact with the operating system. This might give you some ideas: http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?p=849290&posted=1#post849290

Comment: Another idea: various printer companies such as HP have custom APIs for their products. Such printer APIs almost certainly provide ways for telling when a job is done printing. If you know the manufacturer then you could write VBA which invokes whatever function they make available. Needless to say, this isn't a good option if your macro has multiple users who have a variety of printers.